# Crontab not working with inner unix command

Tags: cron, command-line, date

I have following crontab entry which does not work. Please can anybody help?

```
@midnight scp /home/xxx/file.txt xxx@yyy:~/zzz/file.txt_`date +"%m-%d-%y"`
```

This command works very well when run from command line. This is trying to backupo file to another machine every day with current date appended to it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a little-known, but [documented](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/crontab.5.html) feature of cron: if you put a percent sign in a command, it's interpreted as a newline. You need to protect it with a backslash.

```
@midnight scp /home/xxx/file.txt xxx@yyy:~/zzz/file.txt_`date +"\%m-\%d-\%y"`
```

Alternatively, put the command in a script and write just the path to the script in the crontab file.